# Popper Tooltip covers event in Fullcalendar Timeline View with auto height

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, tooltip, popper.js

I changed the height property to 'auto' for the FullCalendar, and if there is only 1 resource, the calendar height is very short, and the popover tooltip covers the event. The CSS I am using is what the FullCalendar website provides. It is fine when there are enough resources. What in the CSS or Tooltip configuration do I need to change so the popover doesn't overlap with the event?

[image]

Code: https://codepen.io/adam-silver/pen/QWdBQVO

Tooltip:

```
var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
      title: line1 + " " + line2,
      placement: 'bottom',
      trigger: 'hover',
      //container: '#fullscreen',
      container: 'body',
    });
    var tooltips = info.event.extendedProps['tooltips'] || [];

    tooltips.push(tooltip);
    info.event.setExtendedProp('tooltips', tooltips);
```

CSS:

```
 .popper,
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: #FFC107;
  color: black;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.style5 .tooltip {
  background: #1E252B;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: auto;
  font-size: .8rem;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}
.popper .popper__arrow,
.tooltip .tooltip-arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 5px;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-arrow,
.popper .popper__arrow {
  border-color: #FFC107;
}
.style5 .tooltip .tooltip-arrow {
  border-color: #1E252B;
}
.popper[x-placement^="top"],
.tooltip[x-placement^="top"] {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.popper[x-placement^="top"] .popper__arrow,
.tooltip[x-placement^="top"] .tooltip-arrow {
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.popper[x-placement^="bottom"],
.tooltip[x-placement^="bottom"] {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.tooltip[x-placement^="bottom"] .tooltip-arrow,
.popper[x-placement^="bottom"] .popper__arrow {
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  top: -5px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.tooltip[x-placement^="right"],
.popper[x-placement^="right"] {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.popper[x-placement^="right"] .popper__arrow,
.tooltip[x-placement^="right"] .tooltip-arrow {
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  left: -5px;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.popper[x-placement^="left"],
.tooltip[x-placement^="left"] {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.popper[x-placement^="left"] .popper__arrow,
.tooltip[x-placement^="left"] .tooltip-arrow {
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  right: -5px;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```